# Determination of pKa and molar absorptivity coefficient using spectrophotometry

Tags: analytical-chemistry, spectrophotometry, uv-vis-spectroscopy

> An indicator BPB (Brophenol Blue) is used and dissolved in solutions of various known $\mathrm{pH}$. Then, the absorbance of each solution at 590 nm was measured and the question asks for molar absorption coefficient of the $\ce{HIn}$ form and $\ce{In-}$ form at the 590 nm wavelength.
>
> Derive the relation of absorptivity coefficient $\varepsilon(\ce{HIn})$ and $\varepsilon(\ce{In-})$ to the total concentration of indicator and also the $K_\mathrm{a}$ for the indicator.
>
> Hint: plot the value of $A$ vs $\mathrm{pH}$.

I don't know how to interpret the resulting graph. I tried to derive a relation, but it is not linear with respect to $\mathrm{pH}$. Here I'm determining the relations of absorbance to $\mathrm{pH}$, trying to interpret the graph of $A$ vs $\mathrm{pH}$, but the relations are not linear.

$$[\ce{HIn}] + [\ce{In-}] = c(\text{BPB})$$

$$K_\mathrm{a} = \frac{[\ce{H+}][\ce{In-}]}{[\ce{HIn}]} \quad\to\quad [\ce{In-}] = K_\mathrm{a}\frac{[\ce{HIn}]}{[\ce{H+}]}$$

$$
\begin{align}
A &= \varepsilon(\ce{HIn})\cdot c \\
  &= b\cdot\left(\varepsilon(\ce{HIn})\cdot [\ce{HIn}] + \varepsilon(\ce{In-})\cdot [\ce{In-}]\right) \\
  &= b\cdot\left(\varepsilon(\ce{HIn})\cdot[\ce{HIn}] + \varepsilon(\ce{In-})\cdot K_\mathrm{a}\frac{[\ce{HIn}]}{[\ce{H+}]}\right) \\
  &= b\cdot[\ce{HIn}]\left(\varepsilon(\ce{HIn}) + \varepsilon(\ce{In-})\cdot\frac{K_\mathrm{a}}{[\ce{H+}]}\right) \\
  &= \frac{b\cdot c(\text{BPB})}{1 + \frac{K_\mathrm{a}}{[\ce{H+}]}}\left(\varepsilon(\ce{HIn}) + \varepsilon(\ce{In-})\cdot\frac{K_\mathrm{a}}{[\ce{H+}]}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE!  Please note that formulas can be better expressed with text rather than pictures with \$\ce{ }\$ for chemical formulas/equations, \$ \$ for math term/equations, and \$\pu{ }\$ for units. More information is available in [this meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/23561) Also, take a minute to look over the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) and [tour page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand our guidelines and question policies if you haven't already